# COMException^ on FilePicker PickSingleFileAsync() call

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-cx

I'm trying to make a game (Universal DX11 application) and at some point I need access to image library to allow user to select avatar. But for some reason call of PickSingleFileAsync on picker rises an exception.

```
Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker^ openPicker = ref new Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker();
openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation = Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary;
openPicker->ViewMode = Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerViewMode::Thumbnail; 
// Filter to include a sample subset of file types.
auto filters = openPicker->FileTypeFilter;
filters->Clear();
filters->Append(".png");
openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync();// same exception with create_task(...);
```

Seems like the sample works only if I put it into UI thread. How can I use picker from my own thread?

UPD: HRESULT:0x80004005

Comment: Can you post the exact `HRESULT` of the exception? And just call this from the GUI thread, shouldn't the dialog open as a response to some user action? If so it seems illogical to call it from a non GUI thread.

Comment: The thing is I'm making crossplatform game, so the only thing I need from Windows Universal App is Swap chain panel (ok, and a file picker). I'm dealing with my own threads (std). Just update the post, by the way.
And to be honest I have a little experience with universal apps, that's why I need help.

Comment: Ok, that is simply `E_FAIL`, could be other reasons than non GUI thread, however if on GUI thread it works. There is a way to invoke this through the disptacher, I'll post an example.

Comment: sorry I was a little careless and didn't see that your answer is the thing I was going to tell you to try out. But why do you expect this to even work from a non gui thread?

Comment: As I said, I have very little experience with universal apps. So I used msdn's example to open a picker from my game-updater thread. There is no warnings like 'you should call it from ui thread only, child', so that's why I expected this to work. By the way, thank you for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just decided to call dipatcher's RunAsync to execute this code. But I still have no idea why I cannot open picker inside non-UI thread.